# Loading different components based on route param in Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm building an editor app which supports multiple design templates. Each design template has wildly different set of fields so they each has their own `.vue` file.

I'm trying to dynamically load the corresponding view component file based on params. So visiting `/editor/yellow-on-black` would load `views/designs/yellow-on-black.vue` etc.

I've been trying to do it like this

```js
{
  path: '/editor/:design',
  component: () => {
    return import(`../views/designs/${route.params.design}`)
  }
}
```

But of course `route` is not defined. Any idea on how to work around this?

Comment: Where's that route variable come from ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The route's `component` option is only evaluated once, so that won't work.  Here's a solution using a `Dynamic.vue` view which uses a [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) based on the route param.

Use a simple route definition with route param.  I changed the param name to `dynamic`:

```js
import Dynamic from '@/views/Dynamic.vue';

{
  path: "/editor/:dynamic",
  component: Dynamic
}
```

Create a generic `Dynamic.vue` component that dynamically loads a component from the route param.  It expects the param to be called `dynamic`:

```html
<template>
  <component v-if="c" :is="c" :key="c.__file"></component>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    c: null
  }),
  methods: {
    updateComponent(param) {
      // The dynamic import
      import(`@/components/${param}.vue`).then(module => {
        this.c = module.default;
      })
    }
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    // When first entering the route
    next(vm => vm.updateComponent(to.params.dynamic));
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    // When changing from one dynamic route to another
    this.updateComponent(to.params.dynamic);
    next();
  }
}
</script>
```